# Why does my Wordpress loop keep timing out?

Tags: php, wordpress

I currently have a WP website where users can sign up and listen to a selection of audios. I also have an iOS app that connects to the website, and allows me to push notifications from the website to the iOS app via a custom post type.

Currently I have a get_users foreach loop that will send the notification to every *subscriber* when it's called. However, the website keeps timing out and subsequently only some of the notifications are being sent.

I have around 2800 users on the website. When I've tested this with just 10 users it works as expected.

Is there a way I can amend my code to prevent it from timing out and killing the function?

```
function prefix_admin_custom_notifications() {
    $post_id = $_REQUEST['postid'];

    add_persistent_notice( array(
            'type' => 'success',
            'message' => "Your push notification was scheduled to be sent!"
    ) );
    $content_post = get_field('message', $post_id);
    $msg = strip_tags($content_post);

    $args = array(
        'role' => 'subscriber',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'phone_token',
                'value'   => array(''),
                'compare' => 'NOT IN'
            )
        )
    );
    $member_arr = get_users($args);

    foreach ($member_arr as $user) {
        $phone_token =  get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'phone_token', true );
        if($_REQUEST['data']=='send_audio_notification') {
            sendpush($msg,$phone_token,$post_id,$user->ID,'audio');
        } else {    
            sendpush($msg,$phone_token,$post_id,$user->ID,'push');
        }
    }

    $url = sanitize_text_field(wp_unslash($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']));
    wp_safe_redirect( urldecode( $url ) );
    exit;
}
add_action( 'admin_post_custom_notifications', 'prefix_admin_custom_notifications' );
```

Comment: Does error_log have anything to say? There are many things which can cause the time out. Each server has limited on how long it waits for the script to execute. It can be long DB calls, it can be a long script in general, it can be long response times from other servers.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an offset in your query to prevent it from timing out if you're unable to increase the max execution time or speeding up your push notifications.
A quick and dirty example below. You will have to redirect to admin_post_custom_notifications as long as all users are done.

```
<?php
function prefix_admin_custom_notifications() {
    $post_id = $_REQUEST['postid'];

    add_persistent_notice( array(
            'type' => 'success',
            'message' => "Your push notification was scheduled to be sent!"
    ) );
    $content_post = get_field('message', $post_id);
    $msg = strip_tags($content_post);
        
        
    // Set limit of users per request, push will send to 500 users
    $get_users_per_run = 500;
    
    // Receive the offset for the current query
    $get_users_offset = (isset($_REQUEST['get_users_offset'])) ? $_REQUEST['get_users_offset'] : 0;
    
    $args = array(
        'number' => $get_users_per_run,
        'offset' => $get_users_offset,
        'role' => 'subscriber',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'phone_token',
                'value'   => array(''),
                'compare' => 'NOT IN'
            )
        )
    );
    
    $member_arr = get_users($args);
    
    foreach ($member_arr as $user) {
        $phone_token =  get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'phone_token', true );
        if($_REQUEST['data']=='send_audio_notification') {
            sendpush($msg,$phone_token,$post_id,$user->ID,'audio');
        } else {    
            sendpush($msg,$phone_token,$post_id,$user->ID,'push');
        }
    }
    
    $ref = (isset($_GET['ref'])) ? $_GET['ref'] : $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    $url = sanitize_text_field(wp_unslash($ref));
    
    // If there are less users in result as $get_users_per_run says, we are ready here!
    if(count($member_arr)<$get_users_per_run)
    {
        wp_safe_redirect( urldecode( $url ) );
        exit;   
    }
    
    // Not all users have get the push notification, go on for next run
    else
    {
        // You have to reload the page to your target of choice, make sure you call your action again
        // with this call
        $url = 'https://www.domain.de/?ref='.$ref.'&data='.$_REQUEST['data'].'&postid='.$post_id.'&get_users_offset='.($get_users_offset+$get_users_per_run);
        wp_safe_redirect( $url );
        exit;           
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_post_custom_notifications', 'prefix_admin_custom_notifications' );
```

Comment: I think this has almost solved the issue so thank you. The only issue I'm having is when the page reloads it redirects to "http://3.9.139.249/?ref=http%3A%2F%2F3.9.139.249%2Fwp-admin%2Fedit.php%3Fpost_type%3Dpushnotif&data=send_push_notification&postid=1109&get_users_offset_=%20100" - any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: Great. How does your redirect url look like? I've seen that I've whitespaces after &get_users_offset = '.($get_users..., please remove them.

Comment: Thanks for this, I've just removed the whitespace. With regards to the redirect url, I've just added it to your code snippet above and commented it out so you can see